# Is there a jQuery image and video slideshow library?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Does anyone know of a jQuery library for doing an image slideshow with the add benefit of video embedded in the slideshow viewing area?  Similar to how ESPN.com frontpage works.

Answer (score 2):

Basic jQuery Slider (http://basic-slider.com/) is pretty flexible. You can embed any type of HTML into each slide (images, text, embed video, etc.).

Comment: Great. Very light-weight

Comment: @khedaywi do you know how to put the arrows (next and previous) to outside of the div ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales You can use the absolute position in CSS to place the next and previous arrow wherever you'd like. The easiest was to visually adjust the css for these elements is to use Web Developer tools like Google Chrome's Developer Tools by right clicking on the element and clicking `Inspect Element`.

In regards to the slider example on http://basic-slider.com/ the previous button can be adjusted by setting `ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a` to `left: -49px;`

Comment: Thank you, in case you wonder how I manage to make it, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200574/navigate-through-a-ul-with-clicks-on-a-div

Answer (score 1):

Whoa -- the video resumes when you click back to it in the slideshow!  That's pretty neat... I doubt anyone else out there has done it.  You can come close with Scrollable:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/slideshow.html

Just put a video in one of the tabs instead of an image.

Comment: Link in answer dead - 404 Not Found | Apologies! | We couldn't find what you're looking for..

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) for that.

```
$('#container').cycle({
    /* cycle options here */
    before: function(currEl) {
        // Stop the video, using any video plugin of your choice 
        // (e.g., JWPlayer, MeddiaElementJS, etc.)
        $(currEl).myVideoPlugin('stop');
    },
});
```

And you can attach an event to your video player plugin that advances the cycle to the next slide when video has finished playing.