# Navigate through a ul with clicks on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, html-lists, jquery-tabs

Please take a look at this first: [This is my *JSFiddle* to edit](http://jsfiddle.net/sL5t7/)

I need to put two `div` one to the left, one to the right, they will hold arrows (like this ones: [imageRight](http://homecareconnection.hdsmith.com/imgs/arrow_RightLight.png), [imageLeft](http://homecareconnection.hdsmith.com/imgs/arrow_LeftLight.png)), so when I click on one `div` left or right, it navigates through the `ul` accordingly.
Please take in consideration that they could be more than two list elements.

Seems easy, but I haven't been able to do it, nor find the right example.

Comment: I've been thinking that maybe could use the code from `.click` but not sure...

Comment: So, you want an alternate method to cycle these with image clicks rather than links? Piece of cake. One moment.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Yes, but keeping the tabs, the images must be on the sides. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Before I move further (I have it pretty much working), are you willing to let me restructure the code to not utilize a `ul` for the arrows?

Comment: @NicholasHazel Programming is an art, do what you think it's best!, I'll then modify it to suit me.

Comment: OK, one second. I'll update the answer. Gimme 10 mins.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Maybe you can tell why is that?, why don't want to use ul ?

Comment: A `ul` should be used only when displaying **list-data**. You don't need a **list**, you need some `container` with properties, and some `id`s. [current fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/sL5t7/1/) Working on centering the `iframe` element.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Looking great! Please tell me if you update it later...

Comment: Actually working on it... browser and live version renders fine, but **jsfiddle** is having issues. It is being more difficult than expected to align properly.

Comment: Current Fiddle - Javascript = [current fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/sL5t7/3/) Positioning it is simply not working. I may have to head to bed, but perhaps this has provided an insight into **developing it easier.**

Comment: @NicholasHazel Thank you. I found a library that matches my needs. http://www.menucool.com/slider/slider-with-tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, now I have the solution...

I end up using a plugin called [Awkward Showcase](https://bitbucket.org/awkwardgroup/awkward-showcase/wiki/Home), which is awesome.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211808/how-to-configure-this-tab-slider/21212196) you can find how it got it's final configuration to match exactly what I wanted. You can add some comments there if you like.

`Solution:` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5pSQ/1/embedded/result/)