# How to configure this tab slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, slider

[Awkward Showcase](https://bitbucket.org/awkwardgroup/awkward-showcase/wiki/Home) is awesome.

But how can I move the `button-wrapper` to the top, and instead of numbers, use custom titles.
None of the options seems to set this things. So I guess I need to change the JavaScript files.

As you see here: http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/ the numbers (1,2,3,4...) are on the bottom, I want them up, and put a better name like: Dog, Cat, Fish, ...

---

**Solution:**
http://jsfiddle.net/h5pSQ/1/embedded/result/

---

**Edit:**
Now that it is done, I need to disable the animation (That it doesn't slide, just hide the current and show the next one)

Comment: I would try with css modifications of this: http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/index3.html (hide images, leave captions, put them to the top)

Comment: @nevermind Thank you, but I am a noob, and don't know much of css, jquery, ... can you give me another hint ?

Comment: Open page in e.g. Firefox, use tools->web developer -> inspector to check css for elements you want to modify... Try to modify css according to your needs... Css mods are easier than jquery mods, for sure, try something, and post some code+jsfiddle, when you get stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the plugin, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ss6F5/3/.
Moving the button numbers to the top can be easily done with css, but i did it in the js itself.
You can pass the button names in the "btn_values" attribute as array in the option hash.

```
$("#showcase").awShowcase({
        btn_values : ["one", "two"],//button names that you want to use instead of numbers
        content_width:          700,
        content_height:         470,
        fit_to_parent:          false
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I just did that!, I used pretend(showcase) and with an array I fill the names. Much similar as you. 
One question is that modification to the source acceptable ?, wouldn't it be better to have another file that inherits ?

Comment: You can modify the code and use it in your application, but it would be  much better to have another file that inherits.

Comment: Yes, that would be better.
One question: your version has a thumbnail, but I don't want it, can you remove it from your JSFiddle ?

Comment: That one still has the thumbnails, even though that it is set to false

Comment: Ok I did it, give me 10 minutes, and I'll upload the solution.

Comment: Maybe you know how to disable the animation ? (That it doesn't slide, just hide the current and show the next one)